# SQL LEFT JOIN first row only

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Let's assume we have such data set:

Table: DataTable1

```
ID      ExperienceId   LanguageId    ...
-------------------------------------------
1       1              1
2       1              2
3       1              3
4       2              1
5       2              2
6       2              3
7       3              1
8       3              2
9       3              3
...
```

Table: DataTable2

```
ID      SomeId OtherId LanguageId    ...
-------------------------------------------
1       459    1       1
2       459    1       2
3       459    1       3
4       245    2       1
5       245    2       2
6       245    2       3
7       295    3       1
8       295    3       2
9       295    3       3
...
```

I want to join those tables and get only SomeId column ignoring the LanguageId column. To make it clearer:

```
SELECT
    t2.SomeId AS RequiredId
    -- ...other data mainly from t2
FROM DataTable1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN DataTable2 AS t2 
    ON t2.OtherId = t1.ExperienceId 
    AND t2.LanguageId = 
        (SELECT TOP 1 t1.LanguageId
         ORDER BY t1.LanguageId)
```

This query should return (if it wasn't wrong, clearly) rows:

```
SomeId    ...
----------------
459       ...
245       ...
295       ...
...
```

Now it returns three times of identical data (with only LanguageId different).

I would try to filter it with `WHERE t1.LanguageId = 1` if I was sure it always exists, but I'm not sure. Rows can be with `LanguageId` from 1 to 3, also they can be only with ID 2, etc. Rows surely will have at least one `LanguageId`.

Now my question is: *how can I join tables with unique values with one column completely ignored*?

Comment: Try using `group by LanguageId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping it in another query does the trick?

```
SELECT RequiredId, <all_the_other_fields> from (
SELECT t2.SomeId AS RequiredId
-- ...other data mainly from t2
FROM DataTable1 AS t1
   LEFT JOIN DataTable2 AS t2 
   ON t2.OtherId = t1.ExperienceId 
   AND t2.LanguageId = 
      (SELECT TOP 1 t1.LanguageId
      ORDER BY t1.LanguageId)
   ) group by RequiredId, <all_the_other_fields>
```

or even not extracting the column in the first place?

```
SELECT distinct t2.SomeId AS RequiredId
-- ...other data mainly from t2 BUT not the Language id
FROM DataTable1 AS t1
   LEFT JOIN DataTable2 AS t2 
   ON t2.OtherId = t1.ExperienceId 
   AND t2.LanguageId = 
      (SELECT TOP 1 t1.LanguageId
      ORDER BY t1.LanguageId)
```

Comment: Thank you, first approach works just fine :) Had problems with EF until I saw that my GROUP BY clause was inside inner query, not outside of it. Changed that and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
;with cte as 
(select *, row_number() over (partition by someid order by languageid) rn
 from datatable2)

select * 
from datatable1 dt
left join cte c on dt.experienceid = c.otherid and c.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

For such things when you need to select `top` in the subquery `CROSS APPLY` OR '`OUTER APPLY`' is very handy

```
t2.SomeId AS RequiredId
    -- ...other data mainly from t2
FROM DataTable1 AS t1
OUTER APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 t1.LanguageId
               FROM DataTable2 
               WHERE DataTable2 .OtherId = t1.ExperienceId 
                AND  t2.LanguageId = t1.LanguageId
             ORDER BY t1.LanguageId
             ) AS t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT t2.SomeId AS RequiredId
        -- ...other data mainly from t2
FROM    DataTable1 AS t1
        LEFT JOIN DataTable2 AS t2 
                  ON t2.OtherId = t1.ExperienceId 
WHERE   t2.LanguageId = t1.LanguageId
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this (Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/811b8/12)?:

```
SELECT    dt2.*
FROM      DataTable1 dt1 INNER JOIN DataTable2 dt2
          ON dt1.ExperienceID = dt2.OtherID AND
          dt1.LanguageID = dt2.LanguageID
WHERE     dt2.LanguageID = (SELECT MIN(LanguageID) FROM DataTable1);
```

produces:

```
ID  SOMEID  OTHERID     LANGUAGEID
1   459     1           1
4   245     2           1
7   295     3           1
```