# Join one row only over three tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

(My question has been asked a lot of times with two tables involved, and has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043259/sql-server-how-to-join-to-first-row), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8161438/select-first-record-in-a-one-to-many-relation-using-left-join) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797727/sql-left-join-first-row-only). But I can't figure out how to do the same with three tables involved.)

I have three tables, A, B and C, where A has many B and B has many C. I want to join these tables and select zero or one rows per A, which one should be based on a condition in C.

Example, assume that:

```
SELECT
     a.aId
    ,b.bId
    ,c.cId
FROM
    a
    INNER JOIN b ON b.aId=a.aId
    INNER JOIN c ON c.bId=b.bId
WHERE
    c.someColumn='foo'
```

...yields the following result:

```
aId   bId   cId
===   ===   ===
1     11    101
1     12    102
1     12    103
2     21    201
2     21    203
2     22    202
```

...then I would like to, for instance, retrieve two distinct A-rows, the ones with highest `cId`.

```
aId   bId   cId
===   ===   ===
1     12    103
2     21    203
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH Cte AS (
    SELECT
        a.aId,
        b.bId,
        c.cId,
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.aId ORDER BY c.cId DESC)
    FROM a
    INNER JOIN b
        ON b.aId = a.aId
    INNER JOIN c
        ON c.bId = b.bId
    WHERE c.someColumn = 'foo'
)
SELECT
    aId, bId, cId
FROM Cte
WHERE rn = 1
```